# How to create and store history list in xaml page for a browser control for wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have been working on a browser app for wp7. I thought i would add some extra features to my app. So, I thought i would create a history page for my app. But am new to Isolated Storage and i dont know how to save the history in a new page.xaml and also i want to see and access it, like if i click on any history, it should redirect to that page. Can anyone help me, because am new to these things. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Stack` object in app.xaml.cs lets say `WebHistory`.

`Stack<Uri> WebHistory = new Stack<Uri>();`

Now handle the LoadCompleted event for the browser control.

In the load completed event handler call `App.WebHistory.Push(e.Uri);`

You can bind it to a list where you want to display the links. and tap of the link navigate the browser to that particular link.

I hope this helps